# Warum heißt es "sich auskäsen"

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Weiß jemand wie die folgende Redewendung entstanden ist?

> [**sich auskäsen**](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~sich%20ausk%C3%A4sen&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&suchspalte[]=rart_ou&suchspalte[]=rart_varianten_ou)
>   - Mensch, käs dich doch mal aus!
>   - Wir müssen noch miteinander auskäsen, wie wir das Problem lösen.

Bedeutung ist

> sich beeilen; vorankommen; zu Ergebnissen kommen; etwas ausdiskutieren; besprechen; sich verständigen; unterhalten; abstimmen

Aber warum eigentlich *käsen*?

Comment: Wo sagt man das denn überhaupt? „Regional begrenzt“ sagt dein Link. Eine erste Suche fördert „sächsisch“ zutage. Könnte hilfreich sein zur Feststellung der Etymologie.

Comment: @dakab Mal überlegen, also zumindest im thüringischen/fränkischen Raum kennt man es. Auf die Idee bin ich gar nicht gekommen, dass es so unbekannt ist

Comment: Mein Beitrag zur regionalen Verbreitung: »Auskäsen« ist in Österreich völlig unbekannt (zumindest in den vier östlichen Bundesländern Wien, Niederösterreich, Burgenland und Steiermark, in denen knapp 60% aller Österreicher leben). Über die fünf anderen Bundesländer kann ich es nicht mit Sicherheit sagen, aber wenn »auskäsen« dort gängig wäre, hätte ich das vermutlich irgendwann schon mal gehört. Was ich aber kenne, ist »*ausschnapsen*«. »Schnapsen« ist in Österreich ein sehr verbreitetes Kartenspiel. Wenn man etwas *ausschnapst*, bespricht man es beim Kartenspiel.

Comment: In Kärnten ist mir dieser Ausdruck noch nie untergekommen.

Comment: Habe das noch nie gehört, im Rheinland, Bergischen Land, Westfalen und Baden-Württemberg.

Comment: Mindestens in Mitteldeutschland bekannt und verbreitet, wahrscheinlich ganz Ostdeutschland. Kommt vermutlich von der langen Zeit, die Käse braucht, um zu reifen. Ist sehr umgangssprachlich.

Comment: "miteinander auskäsen" ist meiner Meinung nach nicht ganz korrekt verwendet. Man meinte eher eine Mischung aus "Wir sollten uns mal beide auskäsen..." und "Wir müssen uns noch miteinander einigen...". IMHO handelt es sich hier schon gewissermaßen um eine Verwurstung des Begriffs "auskäsen", was in der sehr umgangssprachlichen Ausdrucksweise wiederum nicht ungewöhnlich ist. Da werden die Begriffe gerne recht phantasievoll variiert. Ich habe aber keine Belege dafür, und darum kann ich dir das nicht als echte Antwort schreiben. Es ist eher mein Sprachgefühl als einer, der aus dieser Ecke ist.

Comment: Vielleicht einer Verballhornung von "quasen" (http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemid=GQ00424), also miteinander bereden? Ich kannte den Ausdruck übrigens auch nicht.

Comment: Habe das noch nie gehört. Klingt aber gut, ab heute gibt es das auch in Hamburg ;)

Comment: Noch nie gehört im bairischen Raum.

Comment: Ich kenne "sich auskäsen" eigentlich nur im Sinne von "sich aussprechen"

Comment: Ich kenne es aus Sachsen, aber nur in der ersten Bedeutung, der Aufforderung "zu Potte zu kommen", oder "aus dem Knick zu kommen", eine Tätigkeit endlich abzuschließen. Die zweite Bedeutung ("besprechen") kann ich für den Landstrich, den ich einigermaßen kenne, nicht bestätigen.

Answer (score 6):

*Käsen* bzw. *auskäsen* scheint wirklich aus dem Molkereiwesen bzw. der Milchwirtschaft zu kommen.
[Hier](http://www.tilsit-ragnit.de/ragnit/ra_tilsiterkaese5.html) ist der Begriff zu finden und es wird klar, warum *sich auskäsen* anstelle von *vorankommen*, *zu einem Ergebnis kommen* gebraucht wird:

Das *Auskäsen* ist, soweit ich das verstanden habe, der erste Schritt der Käseherstellung, bei dem die festen Bestandteile (Käsebruch) aus der dick gelegten Milch gewonnen wird. Das *Auskäsen* ist bei der Käseherstellung also der Prozess, bei dem die Herstellung des Käses entscheidend *voran kommt* bzw. das Ergebnis (langsam) sichtbar wird.

Comment: Würde man dann aber nicht "etwas auskäsen" sagen? Der Käse käst sich ja nicht selbst aus.

Comment: Es geht einfach um den zeitlichen Aspekt. Die Käseherstellung dauert lange. Und wenn man hinmachen soll, soll man - wie der Käse - endlich fertig werden.

Answer (score 1):

Das könnte auch aus den ungarichen kommen,
"kész" heißt fertig umd wird "kääs" ausgesprochen.

Comment: Welcome to German Language! Sei eingeladen die [tour] zu besuchen und das [help] zu lesen. Diese Antwort ist ein wenig kurz.

Comment: Finde ich sehr interessant. Auch vor dem Hintergrund, dass es vor allem im ostdeutschen Raum verwendet wird. Kannst du was zur Etymologie und Verwendung von kesz schreiben? Würde das im Umgang mit Touristen oft gesagt werden?

Comment: Ich finde, das ist eine legitime Vermutung, auch wenn sie kurz ist. Wenn man nicht mehr weiß sollte man auch nicht mehr sagen.